# Ubuntu 10 installer stops after asking for username and password

Tags: ubuntu, installer

I am trying to install Ubuntu 10.10. It's running fine, until I get to the step where it asks me to specify my name, computer name, user name and password. I have filled in all those fields and all of them display a green checkmark. However, the Forward button doesn't enable. The installer continues copying files, and when it's done it says Ready when you are... in the status bar. Still, Forward is disabled.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but I found the answer. I supplied a username that contained a capital letter. The installer didn't display an error, but apparently didn't allow me to continue either.

Changing 'Jorn' to 'jorn' solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the case of your password and/or username. I used non-capitals per advice but the problem persisted.

When I then typed a password, which I had not the first two times, it worked.